# What do I need to do to get accounts-entry working on my meteor project?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I've been looking at this meteor package all evening ([accounts-entry](http://atmospherejs.com/package/accounts-entry)) and I'm getting nowhere fast.

For example, how does this work exactly?  I put the {% assign special = '{{> accountButtons}}' %} line into my html file and only the {{> accountButtons }} part of it was rendered.  Not sure how this is meant to work, can someone explain that?

> {% assign special = '{{> accountButtons}}' %} You can then either add links to those directly, or use the {{ special }} helper we provide to give you the apppropriate links for signed-in/signed-out users. The {{ special }} helper will display a sign-out link and the user's email address when they are signed-in.

I can't seem to find any decent tutorial on how to use this package properly.  I want to use facebook and twitter to login and also have a sign up form.  I expect this is quite a simple task, I just don't know how.  If anyone can point me to a decent tutorial, I'd appreciate it.

When the user has successfully logged in and I redirect them to a 'dashboard' should I simply create a 'dashboard' named template?

Where should the  Iron-Router route example be homed?  Do I need to name the file that it lives in anything special, like routes.js or anything?

Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

From the example websites in the docs it looks like the {{> accountButtons}} is the only required part to make the login buttons appear.